# How to send an email through a shared mailbox using Microsoft.Graph.Core

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an application that is secured by MSAL. I want to send an email through a shared mailbox that the authenticated user has access to.

When trying to sent the email, my IDE highlights the code below with the error "Delete, method or event expected".

```
await graphClient.Users["test@test.com"].SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync();
```

All online examples use similar code, so I'm struggling to see what is wrong with it.

My project has Microsoft.Graph.Core 3.0.0 referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its looks like your using the Kiota based SDK which have removed the Request method and also has a number of other changes that mean the examples your looking at which used the previous version (eg 2.x) won't work.

With the Kiota based SDK you need to use the SendMailPostRequestBody to control the SaveToSentItems as that availble as a parameter of the Send Method eg

```html
var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Me.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody
{
    Message = new Message
    {
        Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Text,
            Content = "The new cafeteria is open.",
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "frannis@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                },
            },
        },
        CcRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    SaveToSentItems = true,
};
await graphClient.Users["test@test.com"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
```